# Error trying to use more than 2 waypoints in new Here Routing API 7.2

Tags: here-api

I have this annoying problem with the new Here Routing API 7.2:

If I want to use more than 2 waypoints (0 and 1) I get error as a responce from the server:

Request:

```
https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.xml?waypoint0=55.67395%2C12.41686&waypoint1=55.6452%2C12.52621&waypoint2=55.9552%2C12.52421&mode=fastest%3Bcar%3Btraffic:disabled%3BboatFerry:-1&language=en_US&verbosemode=0&alternatives=1&app_code=XXXXXX&app_id=XXXXXXXXXX&routeattributes=wp,sm,sc,sh,bb,lg,no
```

ERROR RESPONSE:

```
<ns2:Error xmlns:ns2="http://www.navteq.com/lbsp/Routing-Errors/1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" type="ApplicationError" subtype="NoRouteFound" xsi:type="ns2:RoutingServiceErrorType">
<Details>Error is NGEO_ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETERS</Details>
<AdditionalData key="error_code">NGEO_ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETERS</AdditionalData>
<MetaInfo>
<Timestamp>2016-02-18T15:30:21Z</Timestamp>
<MapVersion>8.30.61.154</MapVersion>
<ModuleVersion>7.2.66.0-1329</ModuleVersion>
<InterfaceVersion>2.6.21</InterfaceVersion>
</MetaInfo>
</ns2:Error>
```

If I take away the waypoin2 in above request it aswers ok:

Request:

```
https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.xml?waypoint0=55.67395%2C12.41686&waypoint1=55.6452%2C12.52621&mode=fastest%3Bcar%3Btraffic:disabled%3BboatFerry:-1&language=en_US&verbosemode=0&alternatives=1&&app_code=XXXXXXXXXX&app_id=XXXXXXXXXX&routeattributes=wp,sm,sc,sh,bb,lg,no,legs
```

OK RESPONSE:

```
<rtcr:CalculateRoute xmlns:rtcr="http://www.navteq.com/lbsp/Routing-CalculateRoute/4">
<Response>
<MetaInfo>
<Timestamp>2016-02-18T13:38:57Z</Timestamp>
<MapVersion>8.30.61.153</MapVersion>
<ModuleVersion>7.2.65.0-1222</ModuleVersion>
<InterfaceVersion>2.6.20</InterfaceVersion>
</MetaInfo>
<Route>
<Waypoint>
<LinkId>-840260969</LinkId>
<MappedPosition>
<Latitude>55.6739539</Latitude>
<Longitude>12.4166495</Longitude>
</MappedPosition>
<OriginalPosition>
<Latitude>55.6739499</Latitude>
<Longitude>12.41686</Longitude>
</OriginalPosition>
<Type>stopOver</Type>
<Spot>0.5252525</Spot>
<SideOfStreet>left</SideOfStreet>
<MappedRoadName>Hvissingevej</MappedRoadName>
<Label>Hvissingevej</Label>
<ShapeIndex>0</ShapeIndex>
</Waypoint>
<Waypoint>...</Waypoint>
<Mode>...</Mode>
<Shape>...</Shape>
<BoundingBox>
<TopLeft>
<Latitude>55.6739539</Latitude>
<Longitude>12.4158812</Longitude>
</TopLeft>
<BottomRight>
<Latitude>55.6408489</Latitude>
<Longitude>12.5263282</Longitude>
</BottomRight>
</BoundingBox>
<Leg>...</Leg>
<Summary xmlns:rtc="http://www.navteq.com/lbsp/Routing-Common/4" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="rtc:RouteSummaryType">
<Distance>11768</Distance>
<TrafficTime>951</TrafficTime>
<BaseTime>951</BaseTime>
<Flags>motorway</Flags>
<Flags>builtUpArea</Flags>
<Flags>park</Flags>
<Text>
..etc
```

Why does it not work with more that 2 waypoints???
This looks like a big fat bug to me, but I cant find anything about it on the here.com or anywhere on the internet... :((

THIS Request with 3 waypoints used to work in the old version 6.2:

```
http://route.nlp.nokia.com/routing/6.2/calculateroute.xml?waypoint0=55.67395%2C12.41686&waypoint1=55.6452%2C12.52621&waypoint2=55.9552%2C12.52421&mode=fastest%3Bcar%3Btraffic:disabled%3BboatFerry:-1&language=en_US&verbosemode=0&alternatives=1&app_code=bSU31J0m--3cnUyNdSj4cw&app_id=dj92lxIBAWPAwMtNxCgm&routeattributes=wp,sm,sc,sh,bb,lg,no
```

OK RESPONSE:

```
<rtcr:CalculateRoute xmlns:rtcr="http://www.navteq.com/lbsp/Routing-CalculateRoute/4">
<Response>
<MetaInfo>...</MetaInfo>
<Route>
<RouteId>
REM8tfQAAAHRkVz-Q9ZLQGgFhqxu1ShAAAAAYETWS0AAAADAUtUoQAAAAAAAAPB_AAAAAAAA8H-XourNKMKGp1dKLwEVoKaWrTWkAAEAAABcSi8BAQAAAOk1pAABAAAAAADA_wEAAAAAAMD_ZSl--Cc6kst_SH8JSB2PGaiMIQUIAAAAlEh_CQgAAABwhiEFCAAAAAAAAP4PAAAAAAAA_s9seQ_mg7mwYJAXWCYYxLg-_P8yOgx7Z_zGqIBBluHNBoM
</RouteId>
<Waypoint>...</Waypoint>
<Waypoint>...</Waypoint>
<Waypoint>...</Waypoint>
<Mode>
<Type>fastest</Type>
<TransportModes>car</TransportModes>
<TrafficMode>disabled</TrafficMode>
<Feature weight="-1">boatFerry</Feature>
</Mode>
<Shape>...</Shape>
<BoundingBox>
<TopLeft>
<Latitude>55.9671898</Latitude>
<Longitude>12.4158802</Longitude>
</TopLeft>
<BottomRight>
<Latitude>55.6408501</Latitude>
<Longitude>12.5335598</Longitude>
</BottomRight>
</BoundingBox>
<Leg>...</Leg>
<Leg>...</Leg>
<Summary>
<Distance>62581.0</Distance>
<TrafficTime>2916.0</TrafficTime>
<BaseTime>2916.0</BaseTime>
<Flags>motorway</Flags>
</Summary>
..etc
```

Can please someone help me solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The combination of a via point (using the `waypoint2` parameter) and alternative routes (using the `alternatives` parameter) is not supported within the **Routing AP**I as a single request.

The **Routing API** reference states:

> `alternatives`
>
> Maximum number of alternative routes that will be calculated and
>   returned. Alternative routes can be unavailable, thus they are not
>   guaranteed to be returned. If at least one via point is used in a
>   route request, returning alternative routes is not supported.

So you can either find:

- a **single** [route from A to B to C](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/routing/route-from-a-to-b-via-c) or
- a **multiple alternate** routes A to B without intermediate waypoints.

Of course if you make two separate requests you could find:

- A to B with alternative routes  **then**
- B to C with alternative routes